# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value - why?

Tags: swift, null, option-type

I'm pretty new to coding in Swift and I'm not too sure what's happening here - can anyone help?

Thanks

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var toDoItems:[String] = []


    @IBOutlet weak var toDoItem: UITextField!

    @IBAction func addItem(sender: AnyObject) {

        toDoItems.append(toDoItem.text)
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) 

        println(toDoItems)



    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 5):

Most likely, your `IBOutlet`, `toDoItem`, was not bound successfully to a `UITextField` in Interface Builder. Check the outlets for your text field in Interface Builder and make sure it's hooked up successfully.

[image]

If the outlet is hooked up properly, another candidate source of this problem is the instantiation of the view controller itself. If you instantiated it programmatically (e.g. `SecondViewController()` instead of `storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(...)`), that would also result in this error.