# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb) on uitextfield

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uikit

I have a LoginViewController with `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` function and inside the function i have this code to create bottom only border for text field,

```
let txt_border = CALayer()
        let txt_pass_border = CALayer()
        let border_width = CGFloat(2.0)
        txt_border.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
        txt_pass_border.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
        txt_border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: txt_login_Email.frame.size.height - border_width, width: txt_login_Email.frame.size.width, height: txt_login_Email.frame.size.height)
        txt_pass_border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: txt_login_Password.frame.size.height - border_width, width: txt_login_Password.frame.size.width, height: txt_login_Password.frame.size.height)
        txt_border.borderWidth = border_width
        txt_pass_border.borderWidth = border_width
        txt_login_Email.layer.addSublayer(txt_border)
        txt_login_Email.layer.masksToBounds = true

        txt_login_Password.layer.addSublayer(txt_pass_border)
        txt_login_Password.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

but while running the app it shows an error 
[image: output Console]

and highlights the code
[image]

what need to do to change this error ???

Comment: it is most likely that txt_login_Emai is nil

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you

Comment: do you know what nil is?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha by nil i know it is nothing/empty. right?

Comment: exactly. so it is most likely that txt_login_Emai is nil and you need to figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

If you override a function, you will have to always call its super. In this case this should be your first line instead of print("border")

```
super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
```

Once this is done, check if

```
txt_login_Email
```

is not nil.

Comment: As You guys mentioned i checked txt_login_Email is  nil or not , it shows nil. so what do i need to change?

Answer (score 0):

So wandering in search of solution in SO i got an answer for my Question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26348996/fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-value-why)
. The Answer by Rob. i have added

```
let loginViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginVC") as! LoginViewController
```

inside Appdelegate.swift files

```
     func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
 let loginViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginVC") as! LoginViewController
    }
```

And the Problem that was faced went gone.

The Problem started when i started using MMDrawerController from a Tutorial. As a beginner in iOS just followed his instructions and find myself in a Pit . just Blaming Myself for my stupidness. And now i need to do the Drawer Stuff again. Hope it helps someone someday.