# error while assigning string to uilabel swift

Tags: swift, uilabel

I have two view controllers one is main ViewController in which at bottom i putted container view and that container is connected to another NewViewController which i want to show in main ViewController.
I'm setting JSON data to NewViewController's label in ViewController 
it gives me error as fatal error : unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

ViewController.swift

```
let nvc = NewViewController()
func someFunction {
     let data = JSON as! NSDictionary
     let result = data["result"] as! NSArray
     let mytitle = result.valueForKey("name") as! NSArray
     let count = mytitle.count - 1
     for index in 0...count {
         let nameOfPlace = mytitle[index] as! String
         print(nameOfPlace) //prints all the names of places
         self.nvc.nameLabel.text = nameOfPlace //Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
     }
```

NewViewController.swift

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value - why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26348996/fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-value-why) (specific) & [What does “fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value” mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu) (canonical)

Comment: Also your viewController should be created with the reference of your storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Do not set any `IBOutlet` of your `UIViewController` before it is displayed.

The `IBOutlet` is probably not initialised yet. I would suggest making a string property, setting it when you initialise your `UIViewController` and setting that text to your `UILabel` in the `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` method.

Hope this helped!

Comment: i did that like Nirav Doctorwala said but didn't worked