# Swift TextField Issue

Tags: ios, swift, textfield, iboutlet

I am trying to print out the text of a `UITextField` to the console when a button is tapped. However, I am getting an error that says it cannot unwrap a nil. By default, I have a value typed into in and when I insert a new value, both produce this error. These `IBOutlets` are appropriately linked.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var entranceFeeTextField: UITextField!

 @IBAction func saveButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

     print("The entrance fee is \(entranceFeeTextField.text)")
 }
```

My class is only conforming to `UITableViewCell` and `UITextFieldDelegate`, and not to `UIViewController`. Could that be the error?

Comment: print("The entrance fee is \(self.entranceFeeTextField.text!)")

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26348996/fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-value-why

Comment: please check your `IBOutlet` connection with the storyboard `UITextFiled` element. To test that just try this: `print(self.entranceFeeTextField)`. If this says `unexpectedly found nil` then it means your connection of UITextField from storyboard to `IBOutlet` is not proper or broken.

Comment: It appears my outlets are connected appropriately. I tried printing print(self.entranceFeeTextField) and I got the same error. Could the connection be messed up some other way?

Comment: It appears you need to go broad now, can you give us a screenshot of the screen and more code of the controller?

Comment: are your added anything in your textfield

Comment: I can't give the specifics of the code because its an idea I am working on. But basically I am using a textfield in a .xib file consisting of a tableviewcell for a tableview within a view controller. The save button and the textfield are within the same viewcontroller so I have no idea what could be causing the error. Do I need to conform to UIViewController for this to work?

Comment: Could you try adding a test like: 
let test1 = self. entranceFeeTextField;
let test2 = self. entranceFeeTextField.text 
and check if either of them are nil?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
  if let text = self.entranceFeeTextField.text {
        print(text)
    }
```

Comment: Still getting the error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. So I think it's just not recognizing that there is anything in the textfield

Comment: That is not possible. You are doing something wrong. Cna you check your outlets.

Comment: Outlets look good! I just removed them and connected them again just to see, and I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var theTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func onButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        print(self.theTextField.text)
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXYaK.png

Comment: UIKit is in my code, I just didn't add to this question

Answer (score -1):

It Should Be Like

```
@IBOutlet weak var test: UITextField!


    @IBAction func btn(sender: AnyObject) {

        let txt = test.text!
        print(txt)
    }
```

Hope It Helps.